# experimental-webgl does not work on Windows Phone 8.1 IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, canvas, webgl

The Following does not work on Windows Phone 8.1 IE (which I believe is IE11):

```
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
```

However, I can get the 2d context successfully. Any advice? I didn't find anything written anywhere about 3d context incompatibility with Windows Phone-IE11.

Comment: Can you run the demo on this site, on the phone: http://get.webgl.org/

Comment: Thanks Ken, for the pointer. The website renders fine on Windows Phone 8.1 IE, however the context is still unavailable when it's hosted on Cordova.